# Node.js as a proxy to AWS S3

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3

I have my items stored in S3 Bucket. I want the user to download them after he makes a purchase. 
So I get the item from S3, do some manipulations and customizations. Then send it to the browser.

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
var file = require('fs').createWriteStream('/tmp/custom.jpg');
console.log("Getting Object From S3");
s3.getObject(params).on('httpData', function(chunk) {
  console.log("Writing");
  file.write(chunk);
}).on('httpDone', function() {
  console.log("Done");
  file.end();
  // is it the right place to watermark the image ?
  console.log("Sending Content");
  file.pipe(res); 
}).send();
```

When running this code the browser keeps waiting until timeout. 
Am I doing right ? 
Is it non-blocking method ? So I can serve multiple customers at the same time ?